# Does SystemBack application full restore option also restore user files except of system files

Tags: linux, backup, data-recovery, metadata

my question is simple I am using systemback in an ubuntu server to prevent server from failing and easily restore back. My question now is the option full restore point restore also user files and generally files not from the system. Because as far as i know in windows restore-backup restores only system files and not the user files

Comment: Seems like this question can be answered easily by googling the problem and some trial and error : https://www.unixmen.com/systemback-restore-linux-system-previous-state

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Vinayak
so if i understand correctly the full restore also restore user files except the obvious system files am i correct?

Comment: @MixalisNavridis seems like it restores everything but I'm not sure since I've never used this piece of software. If you want to create a 'snapshot' of the entire system at a point in time, there are other tools available